# How to handle NPE in the intermediate operations of Optional/Stream?

Tags: java

```
public class Person {
  private String name;
  private Address address;
}
public class Address {
  private City city
}
public class City {
  private String name;
}


Optional.of(Person::getAddress).map(Address::getCity).map(City::getName).orElseThrow();
```

The middle two `.map` may throw NPE because `getAddress` and `getCity` may return null. What's the best approach to handle NPE here?

Answer (score 2):

```
Person person = new Person();
Optional.ofNullable(person.getAddress())
        .flatMap(p -> Optional.of(p.getCity()))
        .flatMap(c -> Optional.of(c.getName()))
        .orElseThrow(NullPointerException::new);
```

Comment: Yes modified Thank you

Comment: If you throw a `NullPointerException` if it doesn't work, `person.getAddress().getCity().getName()` is simpler and easier to understand.